# Spring-boot Thymeleaf: How do I display an entity name from the database and make that name a hyperlink?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hyperlink, thymeleaf

In my application there are users and each user can have many subjects.
I am able to display all the subjects that belong to the current user.

Below is my line of code that displays the subject name:

```
<li class="list-group-item" th:each="subject : ${subjects}" th:text="${subject.subjectName}"
```

I want the user to be able to click on that name and it will bring them to the page for that subject. That link will look something like this:

```
    th:href="@{/viewSubject} + ${subject.subjectId}"
```

So far I have been able to put a "view subject" link beside the subject name but I would rather they can just click the name for the link.

I tried the following and it didn't work, it is displaying the name but it's not clickable if that makes sense:

```
 <div class="container">
<ul class="list-group">
 <li class="success" >My Subjects</li>
<li class="list-group-item" th:each="subject : ${subjects}" 
th:text="${subject.subjectName}" th:href="@{/viewSubject} + 
${subject.subjectId}">
View Subject
</li>
```

Comment: how should the URL look like for the HREF?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli like this: @{/viewSubject} + ${subject.subjectId}

Comment: with a / between viewSubject and the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" th:each="subject : ${subjects}"  >
<a th:href="@{/viewSubject} + ${subject.subjectId}" th:text="${subject.subjectName}" >some text </a>
</li>
```

Maybe this will require some refinement but the  element will be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply do

```
th:href="${'/viewSubject' + subject.subjectId}"
```

but i think you wanted to do

```
th:href="${'/viewSubject/' + subject.subjectId}"
```

this would create a url that looks like `"/viewSubjec/12"` the 12 being the subject id.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
<ul th:each="subject : ${subjects}">
    <li>  
        <a th:text="${subject.subjectName}" 
           th:href="@{/subjects/{subjectId}(subjectId=${subject.subjectId})}>
        </a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

I would stay away from url concatenation. Better to use variables.

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls